# Implementing map for trees in agda - termination checking problem

Tags: functional-programming, agda, termination, purely-functional

I'm trying to implement `Tree`s in agda as follows:

```hs
module Tree where

open import Data.List

data Tree (A : Set) : Set where
  node : List (Tree A) → Tree A
  leaf : A → Tree A

{-
The straightforward solution upsets the termination checker:
mapTree : ∀ {A B} → (A → B) → Tree A → Tree B
mapTree f (node ts) = node (map (mapTree f) ts)
mapTree f (leaf x) = leaf (f x)
-}
```

Since the call to `mapTree f` is not structural recursive, this code is not allowed by the termination checker.  So I have to resort to a mutual recursion:

```hs
mapTree : ∀ {A B} → (A → B) → Tree A → Tree B
mapTree' : ∀ {A B} → (A → B) → List (Tree A) → List (Tree B)

mapTree f (node ts) = node (mapTree' f ts)
mapTree f (leaf x) = leaf (f x)

mapTree' f [] = []
mapTree' f (t ∷ ts) = mapTree f t ∷ mapTree' f ts
```

The problem is that this is an unnecessary repetition and specialization of a library function `map`, and requires knowledge of the internal workings of `List`s (imagine if one decides to switch to `ℕ → A` later).

How is this problem usually dealt with?  More generally, is there some sort of tricks/idioms to keep the termination checker happy without breaking layers of abstraction and encapsulation?

Comment: Termination checkers only handle structural recursivity. All the variants to prove termination are actually overlays on structural recursivities, such as sized types, well-founded orders and such. Ultimately, these all unfold to structural recursion. Passing the function your are defining as parameter for a function call will always result in a termination checking fail as far as I know, unless you disable it with the terminating pragma, of course, but it makes your whole project unsafe.